# I want to place an image in tpp presentation in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I want to place an image in a [tpp](http://www.ngolde.de/tpp.html) presentation. I am using the code below to show the image

```
--exec shotwell Desktop/a.png
```

However when I run `tpp filename.tpp` then it is showing me this error below:

```
--exec disabled by default for security reasons. Use option -x to enable it.
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do as the error message suggests, i.e., running

```
tpp -x filename.tpp
```

, yet?

<del>However, do you actually want to start shotwell rather than displaying that image inside your presentation. (I don't know whether tpp supports displaying images.)</del>

I've looked at the tpp example files included in the [tpp 1.3.1 source tarball](http://www.ngolde.de/download/tpp-1.3.1.tar.gz) and it doesn't seem like picture file display within the presentation is supported. In the `README` file in the same tarball, it is indeed mentioned that `--exec <cmd>` may be used in the input files to start image viewers. So your approach seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I just want to display the image... how do I do that; which code that I need to use in order to display the image... thank you

Comment: I've installed tpp 1.3.1 from the ubuntu 12.04 package repositories and the `--exec` directive in input files is processed without me having to pass `-x` on the command line. But maybe you've got a different version or variant of the program. Have you tried passing `-x`, yet?